# Using different sets of page objects with the same selenium tests

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, pageobjects, page-factory

[This is cross-posted with SQA - https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/35081/using-different-sets-of-page-objects-with-the-same-selenium-tests]

I'm working on a selenium test suite for a set of similar websites. The test suite would be execute separately for each site and the tests in the suite are applicable to all websites.

These websites are built on the same underlying platform, however have different theme/scheme and therefore page objects for these sites need to be different.  This is not a case of one or two selectors being different, but majority of selectors different - yet the rest of the structure is the same.

I can easily create two (or three, or whatever) sets of page objects, however I can't figure out how to tell the test executor (Cucumber cli in my case) which page objects to use.

The closest I can come up with is use different package names with common base classes and then individual pages extending from the common base classes. Another possibility is to extract all the selectors into property files and load one or another based on an input parameter, however this would preclude me from using PageFactory. I can also, probably, create separate sets of page objects in different source sets and then compile one or the other based on my need - but, again, I can think of the theory, yet not the execution.

So, what's the right approach and how to achieve this?  If it matters, the project is built using gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be a custom ElementLocator and ElementLocatorFactory with a corresponding custom annotation.  It's a bit more work, but it's a very clear solution.  I published it on [github](https://github.com/shchukax/search-with). In short, the implementation allows to do this:

```
public class MyPage {
    @SearchWith(page="MyPage", name="myElement", locatorsFile="{locators}")
    WebElement someElement

    ...
}
```

Then run the whole test with `-Dlocators=site1.json` or `-Dlocators=site2.json` - and corresponding locators will be loaded from one or the other. It even allows to specify `-Dlocators=[site3.json]` and load locators from `site3.json` resource (as obtained using `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(locatorsFile)`)

Answer (score 0):

Since the tests are suitable for all the sites I will assume the only difference between the pages is the selectors behind the objects.

`cssSelector` and `xpath` provides `or`. Assuming text field has ID `id1`, `id2` or `id3` depends on the page you can use

```
@FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = "#id1, #id2, #id3")
private WebElement textField;
```

This will return the `WebElement` matching one of the ids.

Comment: Thanks - that would be too simple.  Majority of selectors are by css and they are conflicting.  For example, I have selector for "product list items", which is `li.Lb` in one theme, but `li.Lc` in another.  Yet, `li.Lb` is a valid selector in the second one, which will return a set of completely incorrect elements.

Comment: @AleksG There isn't more unique way to locate elements? `li.Lb` doesn't seem to be very unique locator (even if it is unique in specific site). Any way, another option is to override/extend the `FindBy` annotation. This will allow you to add logic to it to support reading from locators property file as you suggested.

Comment: Hm, overriding `FindBy` might actually be an interesting idea - I'll investigate it.